# regex for semver

Tags: regex, semantic-versioning

What is a correct regex for matching [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/)?

It should not match for instance

```
01.1.1
9.8.7-whatever+meta+meta
1.2.3.DEV
1.2.3-0123
1.0.0-alpha_beta
1.2-SNAPSHOT
1.2.31.2.3----RC-SNAPSHOT.12.09.1--..12+788
```

it should match for instance

```
0.0.4
1.2.3
10.20.30
1.1.2-prerelease+meta
1.1.2+meta
1.0.0-alpha
1.0.0-alpha.beta
1.0.0-alpha.1
1.0.0-alpha.0valid
1.0.0-rc.1+build.1
1.2.3-beta
10.2.3-DEV-SNAPSHOT
1.2.3-SNAPSHOT-123
1.0.0
2.0.0+build.1848
2.0.1-alpha.1227
1.0.0-alpha+beta
1.2.3----RC-SNAPSHOT.12.9.1--.12+788
1.2.3----R-S.12.9.1--.12+meta
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Take a look on the bottom of the [SemVer](https://semver.org/) page:

[Is there a suggested regular expression (RegEx) to check a SemVer string?](https://semver.org/#is-there-a-suggested-regular-expression-regex-to-check-a-semver-string)

```
^(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(0|[1-9]\d*)(?:-((?:0|[1-9]\d*|\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*)(?:\.(?:0|[1-9]\d*|\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*))*))?(?:\+([0-9a-zA-Z-]+(?:\.[0-9a-zA-Z-]+)*))?$
```

Comment: Thank you. As this is one of the »official« ones I mark your answer as most helpful — however I am wondering why the one I found is 38 chars shorter and what I may have missed.

Answer (score 3):

A working regex would be

```
^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)\.(0|[1-9][0-9]*)\.(0|[1-9][0-9]*)(-(0|[1-9A-Za-z-][0-9A-Za-z-]*)(\.[0-9A-Za-z-]+)*)?(\+[0-9A-Za-z-]+(\.[0-9A-Za-z-]+)*)?$
```

Working against every flavor available at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com)

This is a somewhat simpler version missing the capture groups from the »official« one if you don’t need those and want to keep it simple.

Comment: This is susceptible to a Regular Expression Denial of Service. The form `[1-9]+[0-9]*` can have polynomial runtime. Dropping the `+` and using `[1-9][0-9]*` will have identical behavior with linear runtime.