# How to include checks for a number embedded in a string in json schema?

Tags: jsonschema

I have a field `version` in my json schema that represents a SchemaVer (e.g. `1-0-1`). I am now adding a field, it is backwards compatible so I bump the last number `1-0-2`. But I want to make sure that this new field is *only* allowed when version is *at least* `1-0-2`.

I can't use a pattern (or rather, I don't want to enumerate all versions) since I'd have to specify the idea: For `X-Y-Z`, this field is valid when `Y >= 0` and `Z >= 2`.

Is this something that is possible in JSON schema? Or should I instead go for three fields denoting the version instead?

I looked for using capture groups with jsonschema, but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this with the regex for semver

*stick tap for this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72900791/8564731*

This states, version must be 1.0.2 or greater for any other properties to be defined.

`additionalProperties: false` if `version` is <=1.0.1

This also gives you the ability to use suffix versioning like normal semver

- 1.0.1-beta
- 1.0.2-rc
- etc...

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "oneOf": [
    {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "version": {
          "type": "string",
          "pattern": "^(0|[1-9]\\d*)\\.(0|[1-9]\\d*)\\.(0|[2-9]\\d*)(?:-((?:0|[1-9]\\d*|\\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*)(?:\\.(?:0|[1-9]\\d*|\\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*))*))?(?:\\+([0-9a-zA-Z-]+(?:\\.[0-9a-zA-Z-]+)*))?$"
        },
        "newField": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "version",
        "newField"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "version": {
          "type": "string",
          "pattern": "^(0|[1]\\d*)\\.[0]\\.(0|[1]\\d*)(?:-((?:0|[1-9]\\d*|\\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*)(?:\\.(?:0|[1-9]\\d*|\\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*))*))?(?:\\+([0-9a-zA-Z-]+(?:\\.[0-9a-zA-Z-]+)*))?$"
        }
      },
      "required": ["version"],
      "additionalProperties": false
    }
  ]
}
```

Capture groups are inherently available in JSON Schema with the `pattern` property which subscribes to [ECMA262 regex specification](https://ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-262/)